# Contact points for John's ellipsoid

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $K$ is a centrally symmetric convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $E$ is the John's ellipsoid, the ellipsoid of maximal volume inside $K$.

If $E$ and $K$ have exactly $2n$ contact points, say $(\pm x_i)_{i=1}^{n}$, do $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ form an orthonormal basis for the Euclidean norm indiuced by $E$?

Naively, this statement seems true in two dimensions, but I don't know how to prove it. Or my intuition could be wrong.

Edit: removed another question (whether all points on $\partial K$ extreme points implies exactly $2n$ contact points) as it has an easy negative answer (in comments). Hopefully the remaining question is not as trivial.

Comment: Doesn't seem right even for n=2.  Let E be a circle, and K a smooth convex centrally-symmetric curve between E and some regular hexagon circumscribed about E.

Comment: Indeed, the first question is false.

Comment: You may choose a norm, so that $x_i$ forms an orthonormal basis, after that it remains to read and apply the only property of John ellipsoid mentioned in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I am not sure I understand. $K$ is given and $E$ is uniquely determined by $K$. What is it to choose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks true. A necessary and sufficient condition for these points (let $E$ be a standard ball) is that the identity operator $I$ is a non-negative linear combination of projectors $P_i$ on lines through $x_i$: $$I=\sum c_i P_i.\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(\heartsuit)$$
If $x_i$'s are linearly dependent, multiply $(\heartsuit)$ by a vector $y$ orthogonal to all $x_i$'s to get a contradiction. If not, denote by $(z_i)_{i=1}^n$ a biorthogonal system to $x_i$'s and multiply $(\heartsuit)$ by $z_j$ to get $z_j=c_jP_jz_j$. This means that $z_j$ is an eigenvector of $P_j$ with non-zero eigenvalue, thus $z_j$ is parallel to $x_j$. This is what you need.